# GPS PPS out to ADC input

Tags: audio, adc, gps

Little bit of background, we are building recording devices that are battery powered and far enough apart that they can't be connected by wire, each device keeps it own time with a GPS receiver and the recordings are trigged with the PPS signal from the GPS.

Even with this setup we have found that the recordings have about ±30ms jitter between the start of recordings, Then we came up with the idea of splitting out the PPS signal and adding it to the left channel of the recoding as we are recoding only mono to the right channel.

We just used a basic voltage divider to bring the 3.3vdc PPS signal to ~1vDC, this works well and we can see the pulse and align all the recordings to about ±20us in software.

the current signal look like this in audacity:
[image]
the PPS is 100ms wide.

Even though it is working I can't help but feel using a simple voltage divider is not the right way of adding a digital pulse to a ADC input, I would like to see a nice looking square wave myself.

The question is does anyone have a circuit design that will convert a PPS to ADC input and willing to share?

Comment: Can you show your existing circuit design. A summing amplifier seems like a sensible approach but it'd be easier to write up an answer if we had something to refer to.

Comment: This probably cannot be "fixed" since the ADC here is designed for audio frequencies.  PPS doesn't fall into that category.  The curve you see is a result of the internal high-pass filter.  If you can reliably use this signal for your purposes, I think you can just declare success and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Even though it is working I can't help but feel using a simple voltage
> divider is not the right way of adding a digital pulse to a ADC input*

It looks like your waveform is high pass filtered in the same way as any audio signal will be processed. And, it looks like the signal is both high pass filtered when it was recorded and, during play-back. Something very similar to this: -

[image]

Signal produced by this circuit: -

[image]

I would recommend you live with the recording as it stands and, if you want to post-process the less-than-ideal looking waveform into a square-wave shape you can do this with a couple of comparators and a D type flip flop.

Comment: filter could indeed be at the recorder itself since poster is using an audio channel to record the signal.

Comment: @Abel yes, that is what I said in my opening paragraph; there are two high-pass filter mechanisms at play; one during recording and one during playback. The tell-tale signs of cascaded high-pass filters are in the waveform shape.

Comment: If it is recorded audio is storoed into a file and displayed on screen in audio editor, where exactly would it be played back to get applied with another high pass filter?

Comment: @Justme firstly, if you examine the waveform in detail it has to have at least two high-pass filters involved else the rising edge (the 2nd edge) would not go slightly negative when returning to zero so, that's my first point. As to where that 2nd filter is I just cannot say - in fact it's impossible to be sure given the information available hence, why I said "looks like" in my answer. But, if playback doesn't have any high-pass filtering there is still a 2nd order HP filter at work here.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the explanation, we are using off-the-shelf components (RPI and [Scarlett Solo](https://focusrite.com/en/audio-interface/scarlett/scarlett-solo)) as a proof of concept and the Scarlett may very well have the high-pass filtering. but like I said it working and we have our design requirements and a better understanding of what we are seeing and way thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing a logic signal down with a resistor divider is the correct way to send a square wave pulse to an analog input. Only addition might be a low value capacitor to filter out the high frequencies that cause the spike or ringing in the waveform, but that won't help with the overall shape to be square.

Based on the signal waveform the analog input just won't go down to low enough frequencies to keep the signal waveform as a square shape. Likely due to DC removal high pass in hardware or software.

The square wave step has just changed shape to an exponential RC charging curve.

The reason why it does that can only be guessed without knowing which ADC it is or seeing the schematics. But usually the audio is AC-coupled with a capacitor to remove DC before the ADC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no circuit required.

The other answers have explained in detail the problem, but I'll spell it out. You're using the wrong kit. Stop using Audacity for electronics design and get an oscilloscope. Audacity is for slopey sound signals, not vertical pulses.

Get something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HANTEK-Portable-Based-Digital-Oscilloscope/dp/B00EEX1W5G) for £80 (or [this](https://telonic.co.uk/product-category/digital-oscilloscopes/rigol-mso8000-series/) one for a bit more) and your problem will disappear. Something with much smaller input capacitors and faster response time :-)

Comment: An oscilloscope will not help much if the point is to synchronize audio recordings of multiple devices with the PPS signal.

Comment: @Justme _"I would like to see a nice looking square wave myself."_ which Yendor will get making the question moot.

Comment: So you don't think the question was about how to get the square wave to look like square wave in the recorded audio waveform?

Comment: @Justme Nope: _"adding a digital pulse to a ADC input"_, but let's leave that opinion to Yendor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Paul, we did measure the signal going into the recoding device and we where getting a cleanish square wave, only showed in Audacity as the final file is a wav file and this was the only spot we were seeing this wave form.